# Beginner with Lua looping function

Tags: lua

I am new to lua, just started last night. I have written a script for my games and I found its not operated.

There are three functions in my script, they are function: **`function shoot()`**, **`function pickplayer()`** and **`function drinkwater()`**.

1. running the **`function shoot()`** non-stop for 35 seconds
2. and then running **function pickplayer()** right after the **`function shoot()`** completed.
3. Looping step 1 and 2 for 3 times
4. then run the **`function drinkwater()`**

I have run 3 of these functions individually and it worked fine, but when i combined them together, the script just not working as I wish. As it is not able to running the **`function shoot()`** non-stop for 35 seconds before it jumped to other functions

That would be much appreciate if you guys could give me a hand and point out where the problems are, so that i can move forward.

I know it might be too dumb to ask such stupid questions, but for a non-computering person, your help would gain me huge improvement

Please see the script below

```
DESCRIPTION=" first script";
function shoot()
    while true do
        x, y = findImage("/mnt/sdcard/target1.bmp");
        x1, y1 = findImageFuzzy("/mnt/sdcard/b7.bmp", 80);
        if x1 ~= -1 == x ~= -1 and y1 ~= -1 == y ~= -1 then 
            touchDown(0, x, y);
            touchUp(0)          
        end
        coroutine.yield();      
    end
end


function pickplayer()
    while true do 
        if findImage("/mnt/sdcard/df.bmp") then
            touchDown(0, 355, 783)
            touchUp(0)
            mSleep(500);
            touchDown(0, 188, 203)
            touchUp(0)
            mSleep(500);
            touchDown(0, 196, 196)
            touchUp(0)
            mSleep(500);                        
        end
        mSleep(500);
        coroutine.yield();
    end         
end


function drinkwater()
    while true do
        if findImage("/mnt/sdcard/noenoughwater.bmp") then
            touchDown(0, 228, 479)
            touchUp(0)
            mSleep(2000);
            touchDown(0, 178, 223)
            touchUp(0)
            mSleep(2000);
            touchDown(0, 222, 604)
            touchUp(0)
            mSleep(2000);
            touchDown(0, 180, 218)
            touchUp(0)
            mSleep(3000);           
        end
        coroutine.yield();      
    end
end


function main()
    co1 = coroutine.create(shoot);
    co2 = coroutine.create(pickplayer);  
    co3 = coroutine.create(drinkwater); 

    while true do
        local timeToRun = 35000
        local initialTime = os.time()
        local timeElasped=os.difftime(os.time(), initialTime)
        while timeElasped < timeToRun do
            coroutine.resume(co1)
            timeElasped =os.difftime(os.time(), initialTime)
            mSleep(2000);   
            coroutine.resume(co2);
            coroutine.resume(co3);      
        end
    end     
end
```

Comment: What happens when you run your script as written?

Comment: thx for your reply Etan, 
Error not found, just nothing is running

Comment: is there anything wrong on my timer?

Comment: Just tested again, function co1 is working fine, but not co 2 and co3

Comment: What do you mean "nothing is running"? What happens exactly? If you put print/log statements in those functions do you see their output?

Comment: it is like when function co1 is completed, co2 is suppose to running afterward, but the script just freeze there.

Comment: Define "freeze"? Also how do you know it is freezing? Have you tried verifying what things are actually happening with debugging print/log statements?

Comment: Hi Etan , 
I have changed my script and it finally works but then there is a problem, I couldnt non-stop running function co1 for 35 sec before it jump to other functions.
see below

Comment: function main()
    co1 = coroutine.create(shoot);
    co2 = coroutine.create(pickplayer);  
 co3 = coroutine.create(drinkwater); 
  
 while true do
  local timeToRun = 35000
  local initialTime = os.time()
  local timeElasped=os.difftime(os.time(), initialTime)
  while timeElasped < timeToRun do
        coroutine.resume(co1)
        timeElasped =os.difftime(os.time(), initialTime)
  mSleep(2000); 
  coroutine.resume(co2);
  coroutine.resume(co3);  
    end 
  
 end  
end

Comment: I have updated the question and the recent script, hope it would be easier for you to read. I am also tring to get the debug statement .

Comment: What is the issue currently? Because your code doesn't match what you claim to want. There is no "3 times" loop. You don't want until after 35 seconds to run functions two and three.

Comment: Etan, 
someone just edited my code, and i am gonna test it soon :) 
thx for your help anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the touchDown and ups and sleeps are noise, the issue here is "scheduling" of the coroutines. You basically have this:

```
function condition1() return true end -- for testing
function condition2() return true end -- for testing


function shoot()
    while true do
        -- do stuff, then:
        coroutine.yield()
    end
end


function pickplayer()
    while true do 
        if condition1() then
            -- do stuff, then:
            mSleep(1500)                       
        end
        mSleep(500)
        coroutine.yield()
    end         
end


function drinkwater()
    while true do
        if condition2() then
            -- do stuff, then:
            mSleep(9000)       
        end
        coroutine.yield() 
    end
end


function main()
    co1 = coroutine.create(shoot)
    co2 = coroutine.create(pickplayer)
    co3 = coroutine.create(drinkwater)

    while true do
        local timeToRun = 35000
        local initialTime = os.time()
        local timeElasped=os.difftime(os.time(), initialTime)
        while timeElasped < timeToRun do
            coroutine.resume(co1)
            timeElasped =os.difftime(os.time(), initialTime)
            mSleep(2000)
            coroutine.resume(co2)
            coroutine.resume(co3)  
        end
    end     
end
```

The above will do this:

1. run the function shoot()
2. and then run function pickplayer()
3. and then run function drinkwater()
4. Looping steps 1 to 3 forever

However you say you want to achieve this:

1. run the function shoot() non-stop for 35 seconds
2. and then run function pickplayer()
3. Loop step 1 and 2 for 3 times
4. then run the function drinkwater()

This would require your main to do the following (not that repeat-until is nicer here than while-do-end):

```
function main()
    co1 = coroutine.create(shoot)
    co2 = coroutine.create(pickplayer)
    co3 = coroutine.create(drinkwater)

    for i=1,3 do -- do the following 3 times:
        -- shoot for 35 seconds non-stop
        local timeToRun = 35000
        local initialTime = os.time()
        local timeElasped = 0
        repeat 
            coroutine.resume(co1)
            timeElasped = os.difftime(os.time(), initialTime)
        until timeElasped < timeToRun 

        -- mSleep(2000): don't need this

        coroutine.resume(co2) -- pickplayer
    end     
    coroutine.resume(co3)  
end
```

Comment: Hi Schollii, 
thank you so much for editing this for me.

Comment: do i have to put anything inside the function **condition1() return true end** ??

Comment: Replace them with your findImage conditions, I used these so I could focus on structure and schedule.

Comment: schollii, is there anyway that i can talk to you in person? 
I have so much wanna ask you

Comment: do you think you can solve out this problem for me too? 
see link below

Comment: {link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23844493/asking-script-to-action-when-2-moving-objects-come-across-in-same-x-y-coordinat?noredirect=1#comment36693177_23844493)